# How many type conversion are there in the code?

Tags: c, type-conversion, type-promotion

How many type conversion are there in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f(int x)
{
    return (float)x;
}
int main()
{
    float x = f(5L);
    return 0;
}
```

In function `f()`, the return value is promoted from `int` to `float`.
In `main()`, the argument of `f()` is promoted from `int` to `long`, and `int` is again promoted to `float`.

Is it correct that there are three type conversions (promotions)?

Comment: Since `x` is not used, an optimized compile may drop `float x = f(5L);` and zero conversions are done.  Other than that I see 4+ type changes.

Comment: None of the conversions are "promotions".

Comment: What's that casting `int `to `float` to return a value from an `int` function?

Comment: It looks like: long -> int -> float -> int -> float. Does this compile?

Comment: Most likely none - just a return 0 in main

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Keith Thompson No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a total of 4 type conversions (none of which are "promotions").

Inside `f()`, the value of `x` is explicitly converted from `int` to `float` by the cast operator, The result of that conversion is implicitly converted from `float` to `int` by the `return` statement.

Inside `main()`, the value of the constant `5L` is implicitly converted from `long int` to `int` when it's passed as an argument to `f`. The result of the call to `f` is implicitly converted from `int` to `float` by the initialization of `x`.

That's four conversions. (The `return 0;` doesn't involve a conversion, since the `0` is already of type `int`, which is the return type for `main`.)

Given a reasonably clever compiler, it's likely that none of these conversions will result in any non-trivial generated code. Since none of the values are used, the entire program could be reduced to the equivalent of

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

But all four conversions occur in the "abstract machine" defined by C's semantics.

(Incidentally, `int main(void)` is preferred to `int main()`.)

Comment: Is the conversion from long int to int a demotion?

Comment: @display_error: If you want to call it that, sure, but I wouldn't. The C standard doesn't use that word. It does specifically define the term "*integer promotions*" (see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.1); there are none in the code in the question.

Comment: @display_error: Correction: The C standard does use the word "demotion" to refer to a floating-point conversion in J.2 -- but it's an informal use of the term in non-normative text.

Comment: Why the conversion from int to float is not a promotion (it is not an integer promotion, but why not a promotion)?

Comment: @display_error: Simply because the standard doesn't call it a "promotion". You can call it that if you like, I suppose -- but there are likely to be values of the `int` that cannot be represented exactly in type `float`, and certain to be values of type `float` that are outside the range of `int`, so why should a conversion in one direction or the other be called a "promotion"?

Answer (score 2):

In `f`:

`int` (argument) -> `float` (cast) -> `int` (return value)

In `main`:

`long` (literal) -> `int` (argument)

`int` (return value of f) -> `float` ( variable x)

That's four conversions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct answer to this question - it all depends on the compiler and the system used.

A good compiler will through everything except the `return 0;` away and there will be no conversions at all.

Even if the compiler still keeps the function, the number of conversions is still unpredictable. The `5L` to `int` conversion will be resolved at compile time. So it shouldn't count as a conversion. Also on many system there is no difference between `long` and `int` as they are both 32 bits (on many systems) which again suggest this isn't a conversion.

On most systems, the ugly `(float)` cast causing `int->float->int` will have to stay as a `float` can't represent all values of an `int`. But if the system uses a float format that can represent all `int` values, the compiler may through the conversions away. The `int->float` in main would have to stay.

So I would say either 0, 1 or 3 conversions. With 0 being mostly likely when compiling with optimization.

But the real answer is - it is system and compiler dependant.